American persimmon - black spots on leaves and fruits



What's these black spots on leaves? They are also visible on the fruits, is it some kind of fungal infection?

Maybe Sooty Mold?

Looking what Wikipedia says: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sooty_mold it's similar, but it seems that's somenthing different, because black spots can't be removed, it;s not on leaves surface and there's no any white mold on the branches. It' rater looks like some kind of leaf spot, but I;m not sure what is it.
